# Setting a recycler view/cardview with grid layout within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-recyclerview, cardview

I try to adopt a program that uses Recyclerview and card view to display a grid layout (In this case, a library of books) within a single fragment. This is the original method. It was within a MainActivity method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Book> lstBook;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lstBook = new ArrayList<>();
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Vegitarian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thevigitarian));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Wild Robot","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thewildrobot));
        lstBook.add(new Book("Maria Semples","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.mariasemples));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Martian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.themartian));
        lstBook.add(new Book("He Died with...","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.hediedwith));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Vegitarian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thevigitarian));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Wild Robot","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thewildrobot));
        lstBook.add(new Book("Maria Semples","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.mariasemples));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Martian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.themartian));
        lstBook.add(new Book("He Died with...","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.hediedwith));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Vegitarian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thevigitarian));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Wild Robot","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thewildrobot));
        lstBook.add(new Book("Maria Semples","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.mariasemples));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Martian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.themartian));
        lstBook.add(new Book("He Died with...","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.hediedwith));

        RecyclerView myrv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
        RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,lstBook);
        myrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
        myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

And this is what I've tried to do. I'm trying to mimic the same thing within a fragment:

```
public class LibraryFragment extends Fragment {

    List<Book> lstBook;
    RecyclerView myrv;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter myAdapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_library, null);

        lstBook = new ArrayList<>();
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Vegitarian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thevigitarian));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Wild Robot","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thewildrobot));
        lstBook.add(new Book("Maria Semples","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.mariasemples));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Martian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.themartian));
        lstBook.add(new Book("He Died with...","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.hediedwith));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Vegitarian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thevigitarian));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Wild Robot","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thewildrobot));
        lstBook.add(new Book("Maria Semples","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.mariasemples));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Martian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.themartian));
        lstBook.add(new Book("He Died with...","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.hediedwith));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Vegitarian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thevigitarian));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Wild Robot","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thewildrobot));
        lstBook.add(new Book("Maria Semples","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.mariasemples));
        lstBook.add(new Book("The Martian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.themartian));
        lstBook.add(new Book("He Died with...","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.hediedwith));

    **myrv = (RecyclerView) myrv.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        myAdapter = new myAdapter(lstBook);
        myrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
        myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);**
    }
}
```

I'm running into some trouble with the last four lines of code where I can't resolve myAdapter and the GridLayoutManager not being properly applied. Does anyone have any pointers to resolve my problem? Or can someone point me to a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Any code after **return** will be unreachable, so **return** should be the last row. Also in fragment, **this** is not correct, change it to **getContext()** or **getActivity()**. Try the following code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_library, null);

    lstBook = new ArrayList<>();
    lstBook.add(new Book("The Vegitarian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thevigitarian));
    lstBook.add(new Book("The Wild Robot","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thewildrobot));
    lstBook.add(new Book("Maria Semples","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.mariasemples));
    lstBook.add(new Book("The Martian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.themartian));
    lstBook.add(new Book("He Died with...","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.hediedwith));
    lstBook.add(new Book("The Vegitarian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thevigitarian));
    lstBook.add(new Book("The Wild Robot","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thewildrobot));
    lstBook.add(new Book("Maria Semples","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.mariasemples));
    lstBook.add(new Book("The Martian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.themartian));
    lstBook.add(new Book("He Died with...","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.hediedwith));
    lstBook.add(new Book("The Vegitarian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thevigitarian));
    lstBook.add(new Book("The Wild Robot","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.thewildrobot));
    lstBook.add(new Book("Maria Semples","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.mariasemples));
    lstBook.add(new Book("The Martian","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.themartian));
    lstBook.add(new Book("He Died with...","Categorie Book","Description book",R.drawable.hediedwith));

    myrv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    myAdapter = new myAdapter(getContext(), lstBook);
    myrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3));
    myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I_A_Mok - Thank you sir. I was able to straighten out my issue with your help. I did an "upvote" to note that your resolution helped in resolving my issues.